# Cypress accessing shadow dom internals

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to access a slider within shadow dom in a Cypress test.

This is what the control looks like in dev-tools.

```js
<input type="range">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
  <div>
    <div pseudo="-webkit-slider-runnable-track" id="track">
      <div id="thumb"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Have added `includeShadowDom: true` to config, but am unable to access `div#thumb` with either of these commands.

```js
cy.get('div#thumb')

cy.get('input[type="range"]')
  .find('div#thumb')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `#shadow-root (user-agent)` so this shadow dom is created by the browser, not the web page.

You can't access a Shadow DOM created by the browser to display a control, that is called a #shadow-root (user-agent) in the Dev Tools.  is one example.

You can only access open custom Shadow DOM (the ones that you create yourself), with the { mode: 'open' } option.

If you try the following, it will log `null`

```js
cy.get('input[type="range"]')
  .then($input => {
    console.log($input[0].shadowRoot)    // null means shadow dom is inaccessible
  })
```